# Problem highlighting binary units with soul and siunitx packages

Tags: siunitx, highlighting, soul

I am trying to highlight text that includes quantities using the siunitx package. Just as when highlighting other commands like \cite, they have to be enclosed in extra brackets. But a problem occurs when using binary units (\bit, \byte, \kibi\byte) which give an *Undefined control sequence* error. Other units like microseconds or megahertz are highlighted with no problem.

I leave a MWE. Appreciate any help I can get.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        binary-units = true,
    }

\begin{document}

% These are OK
\hl{{\SI{32}{\MHz}}}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\us}}}

\SI{32}{\bit}

\SI{32}{\byte}

\SI{32}{\kibi\byte}

% These give errors
\hl{{\SI{32}{\bit}}}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\byte}}}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\kibi\byte}}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\protect` seems to remedy the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        binary-units = true,
    }

\begin{document}

% These are OK
\hl{{\SI{32}{\MHz}}}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\us}}}

\SI{32}{\bit}

\SI{32}{\byte}

\SI{32}{\kibi\byte}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\protect\bit}}}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\protect\byte}}}

\hl{{\SI{32}{\protect\kibi\protect\byte}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]